# Problem with Workbench

Tags: database

I am on Debian stretch, I am using PHP 7.1, Here is the output Info from Workbench.

```
> MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Linux/Unix version 6.3.8 CE build 1228 (64 bit)
Configuration Directory: /home/me/.mysql/workbench
Data Directory: /usr/share/mysql-workbench
Cairo Version: 1.14.8
OS: Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64
CPU: 12x AMD Ryzen 5 2600 Six-Core Processor (1550.000MHz) - 15,67GiB RAM
Distribution: Debian GNU/Linux 9.9 (stretch)
Fips mode enabled: no
```

When I try it from my Browser **http://localhost:3306/** , it redirects me to the following window:

[image]

I do not know what does it mean!

When I change the port of local Instance to 3306, I get this:

```
> Connection Warning (Local instance 3306)
Incompatible/nonstandard server version or connection protocol detected (10.1.38).
A connection to this database can be established but some MySQL Workbench features may not work properly since the database is not fully compatible with the supported versions of MySQL.
MySQL Workbench is developed and tested for MySQL Server versions 5.1, 5.5, 5.6 and 5.7
```

I have read that MariaDB and mysql-server, together making Problem on Workbench, but when I do  `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`, too install MariaDB.. , when going to **Synaptic** and lose MariaDB , Mysql-server not Working...

In Synaptic when to search to install **mysql-server** , to show this Window
[image]

How to see, too is MariaDB...[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417306/how-to-install-only-mysql-on-debian-gnu-linux-9-stretch-without-mariadb) a person has a similar problem as me.
I have tried to install Mysql-server from [MySQL APT Repository](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) , 
[image]

but it does not do anything.

Now I know how to install it.., [here](https://tecadmin.net/install-mysql-server-on-debian9-stretch/) tell how does it..

Now have it..

With `$ mysql --version`

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

However, my browser shows the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so , now working !

**The problem**

In Debian Stretch when Install Mysql with,

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

it install  togheder Mysql and MariaDB ..and **Workbench** will not...Workbench will **only** working with Mysql **without** MariaDB .

**The solution**

I think that Best remove ALL , from Mysql and Workbench , and start from Zero .

- First , **bevor** and **very important** , your muss to **save** you configuration (Tabelle,..) out from Mysql File (i tell you this , because i build my Tabelle with phpmyadmin , and phpmyadmin save the Tabelle on Mysql File..i don't knew it , and lose all my Tabelle....)
- We muss lose Mysql , you muss to know who Mysql version you have , with this , you know it , `$ mysql --version`

I to come,

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

I have Mysql 5.7 , now i will it to lose with ,

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7
```

Because on Debian Stretch repository , Mysql is togheder with MariaDB , we to search an Alternative , us alternative to be called , **MySQL APT Repository** .We Download it from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) .

I Download this ,

> mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb

and Install it wit **dpkg**,

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
```

it open a Window ,
[image]

on **Mysql Server & Cluster....**, give Enter , you decider from one of they,I to decide from Mysql 5.7.., and come back to these Window .Give enter on small **ok** , NOT to Big OK ! .

[image]

Now , we will update it,

```
$ sudo apt update
```

and install intall it with,

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Now have Install mysql-5.7 from **MySQL APT Repository** , not from Debian Repository , therefore have **only** Mysql without MariaDB .

Now Download and install Workbench with

```
$ sudo apt -y update

$ sudo apt -y full upgrade

$ sudo apt -y install mysql-workbench
```

Now ,we open Workbench , I have Debian Stretch Mate.. , Top Left ,to Applications + Development , we have us Workbench..

When all ok is, it will start without Warning....

Sorry about my English , I hope your Understand me...

Answer (score 3):

You're using **MySQL** Workbench, but according to the output when you connect to the database port with a browser, the database is actually **MariaDB**, which is a competing fork of MySQL.

As MySQL Workbench is developed together with MySQL, the developers obviously cannot guarantee full compatibility with a competitor product.

(In practice, though, any feature of MySQL Workbench that is based on basic features of MySQL database developed before the fork will probably work just fine. With new features introduced after MariaDB was forked off, you might have to be more careful.)

The port 3306 is the default port of MySQL/MariaDB, and it is intended for direct connection between applications and the database: it won't provide HTTP access. This is why your connection attempt with a browser produced a string of binary garbage with some snippets of text mixed in: it is not meant to be connected with a browser.

Comment: Very thank for your answer , can please you read my Question , i have it new Edit.

Comment: You are not supposed to connect to MySQL port 3306 with a web browser. It does not work that way.